# Tell the user he must use a LongClick

Tags: android, google-maps, onlongclicklistener

I have a google map application. People can add markers with a longclick.
I wonder what should be the best strategy to tell him to use longclick to add marker, because I don't think it is so obvious.
Should I use DialogFragment once? Should I use a menu Instructions? Or maybe the user is already used to it and there is no need to tell him?

Any advise would be apreciated !

Comment: Maybe you could handle the simple click with a Toast which informs the user about the longclick method

Comment: You should pop an overlay for the first 3 or 4 runs. In this view, just explain what the user is expected to do and the way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give demo to the user at the about the working of your application, and continue give him that until he will click the check box 'don't show this again', or make some tutorial option in your application which tell it's working.